# Implementation unity interception with single interface and container definition

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unity-container, interceptor

i would like to use unity interception for logging in Asp.Net MVC my project. I have a lot of classes. But i need to decrease the quantity of definition related with unity.Do i have to create an interface for each class? Furthermore, i have a lot of methods in each class and do i have to create unity proxy objects for each method calls that invokes logging method. Can i perform these operations inside global.asax file for one time and use in my whloe project. Is there such a way or method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, you don't have to create an `interface` for each class, that destroys the point of an `interface`.

If you are using the same methods, but the implementation of them is different, than use an interface. If its the same exact method, consider moving the methods into some sort of a manager `class` or use some form of inheritance.

Comment: Well, what if i have completely different methods in my classes?. For example i have authentication and authorization classes and  their methods are different. How can i create and use an interface for both of these classes?

Comment: Are you referring to the C# ´interface´ keyword or a generic programming interface? The C# ´interface´  lists a name of function signatures to classes need to impliment, but they can be implimented in anyway, however they have to have the same names. I'm not sure these too classes would share any of the same methods.